# How to translate vim keycode to byte sequence that triggers it?

Tags: vim, ansi-escape

When using the `:map` command, you can specify key sequences, 
for example `<c-a>` which means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and it is triggered by '\x01' (represented as '^A')

However, there are combinations not possible to send by some Terminal emulators natively, like the famous <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>, and you should attribute yourself the sequence it should produce, and then you can map it in vim.

But I was wondering, maybe vim already expects some sequences to trigger a  sequence, and I would like to know if one can get what sequence triggers a vim key combination (like , or  etc.) ?

Answer (score 0):

The [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) wikipage is explaining how these combinations work.

On Linux, you might also try the [xev(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xev) utility.